# php Matching javascript value

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I'm attempting to run preg_match to extract the text attribute from the first value in an javascript code.

```
preg_match('/^\[\[\["(.*)"/i', $data, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

from

```
[[["text to extract"," ...
```

or

```
[[["text to extract",[[ ...
```

matches much text: *text to extract",["...*

Need onli from [[[" to next ".

Comment: what do you want to extract from `[[["text to extract"," ...` or `[[["text to extract",[[ ...` ?

Comment: It is dynamic, what I know is that the text always ends with double quotes. Accept any character without double quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Regex should work,

```
\[\[\["(.*?)"
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pH2bM1/2)

It is capturing `text to extract` from `[[["text to extract"," ...`

It uses the concept of [Group capture](http://regexone.com/lesson/11)

Comment: Thanks! :D works fine. because the first double quote comes without backslash and the second we?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are almost there. Just adding the comma to the regex:

```
preg_match('/^\[\[\["(.*)",.*/i', $data, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

And now "text to extract" is in $matches[1][0]

Comment: Not work. result: description."]],,"en",,,[["SVM",1,

Comment: What if the text contains escaped quotation mark (`\"`)?

Comment: when he brings is encoded in unicode quotes \u0000 because the string is an array in javascript